# Use zipTree as source set for building and static compiling

Tags: java, gradle, jar, code-generation, dependency-management

## Background

Project Alice generates Java source code, stores it in `sources.jar`, then uploads it to a Maven repository. Project Bob pulls `sources.jar` down and needs to use it when compiling. Bob does not know that Alice exists, only where to find `sources.jar`.

Versions: JDK 11, Gradle 7.3.1, IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1

## Problem

Making gradle (and IntelliJ's IDEA) build using source files embedded in a JAR file. To be clear, the JAR file contents resemble:

```sh
$ jar -tvf sources.jar 
     0 Thu Feb 03 08:38:56 PST 2022 META-INF/
    52 Thu Feb 03 08:38:56 PST 2022 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Thu Feb 03 08:38:30 PST 2022 com/
     0 Thu Feb 03 08:38:32 PST 2022 com/domain/
     0 Thu Feb 03 08:38:30 PST 2022 com/domain/package/
   938 Thu Feb 03 08:38:32 PST 2022 com/domain/package/SourceCode.java
```

Solutions that extract the `.java` files from the `.jar` file introduce knock-on effects we'd like to avoid, including:

- **Editable.** Extracted source files can be edited in the IDE. We'd like them to be read-only. We could add a task that sets the files read-only, but that feels like solving the wrong problem (added complexity).
- **Synchronization.** When a newly generated `sources.jar` is pulled down, we'll have to delete the extraction directory to remove any stale .java files that were preserved. If there was a way to avoid extraction, then the act of pulling down the new `sources.jar` file would ensure correctness (no added complexity). By unarchiving the .java files, it's possible to enter an inconsistent state:

```sh
$ jar -tvf sources.jar | grep java$ | wc -l
61
$ find src/gen -name "*java" | wc -l
65
```

If there was a way to treat `sources.jar` as a source directory without extracting the files, these knock-on effects disappear.

## Attempts

A number of approaches have failed.

### sourceSets

Changing `sourceSets` doesn't work:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += "jar:${projectDir}/sources.jar!/"
```

The error is:

> Cannot convert URL 'jar:/home/user/dev/project/sources.jar!/' to a file.

Using a zipTree with `sourceSets` doesn't work, although the error message is telling:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += zipTree(file: "${projectDir}/sources.jar")
```

Error:

> Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI.
>
> The following types/formats are supported:
>
> - A URI or URL instance.

This was expected. What was unexpected was that URL instances are allowed, but seemingly not if embedded within a JAR file.

The following allows building Bob, but the IDE is unable to find `SourceCode.java`:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += zipTree("${projectDir}/sources.jar").matching {
  include "com"
}
```

### build task

Modifying the build task to extract the generated code first partially works:

```
task codeGen {
  copy {
    from( zipTree( "${projectDir}/sources.jar" ) )
    into( "${buildDir}/src/gen/java" )
  }

  sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += ["${buildDir}/src/gen/java"]
}

build { doFirst { codeGen } }
```

The issue is that removing the `build` directory then prevents static compiles (because IDEA cannot find the generated source files). In any case, we don't want to extract the source files because of all the knock-on problems.

### compile task

The following snippet also does not compile:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  source = zipTree(file: "${projectDir}/sources.jar")
}
```

Not updating `sourceSets` means that the IDE cannot discover the source files.

### sync task

We could extract the files into the main source directory, instead, such as:

```
def syncTask = task sync(type: Sync) {
    from zipTree("${projectDir}/sources.jar")
    into "${projectDir}/src/gen/java"

    preserve {
        include 'com/**'
        exclude 'META-INF/**'
    }
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDir(syncTask)
```

While that addresses the clean issue, we’re left with the original problems that we’d like to avoid.

### Content Root

Setting the Content Root and marking the Source Folder from within IntelliJ IDEA works. The IDE updates `.idea/misc.xml` to include:

```xml
  <component name="FrameworkDetectionExcludesConfiguration">
    <file type="web" url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$" />
    <file type="web" url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/project/sources.jar!/" />
  </component>
```

In theory, the `idea` plugin may have the ability to set this value.

## Question

How would you instruct Gradle to reference and build using source files that are stored in an external Java archive file when compiling a project (*without* extracting the archive) such that IDEA can statically resolve the source files, as well?

Comment: Why don't you just use a compiled jar?

Comment: The generated source code is from a different project and cannot be compiled separately because of circular dependencies. The projects cannot be merged. (If we could merge the projects, then we would add a task to build.gradle as a precondition to building.) We can also use a git submodule, but we'd like to avoid that rabbit hole as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Working Solution

I first believed it wasn’t possible to use a JAR file containing uncompiled Java code as additional sources in IntelliJ. After a few tries I could eventually configure it in the UI, though, thanks to the pointer from your “Content Root” section. A bit of fiddling with the [IDEA plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/userguide/idea_plugin.html) later, I could finally come up with a fully working solution:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    source(zipTree("${projectDir}/sources.jar"))
}

idea.module.iml {
    withXml {
        def baseUrl = 'jar://$MODULE_DIR$/sources.jar!/'
        def component = it.asNode().component[0]
        def jarContent = component.appendNode('content', [url: baseUrl])
        jarContent.appendNode('sourceFolder', [
                url: "${baseUrl}com",
                isTestSource: false,
            ])
    }
}
```

Before opening the project in IntelliJ, you’ll have to run `./gradlew idea` and then open the generated `.ipr` file with IntelliJ. If IntelliJ says “Gradle build scripts found”, then *don’t* attempt to load the Gradle project but instead “Skip” this. You now have an IntelliJ project which is generated by Gradle but which is still independent of Gradle – and hence you can safely call `./gradlew clean` without affecting IntelliJ.

### Other Thoughts

Here’s another approach of configuring the compiler from Gradle, using the (rarely used) [`-sourcepath` option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9) of `javac`:

```groovy
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.sourcepath = files("${projectDir}/sources.jar")
}
```

I personally would still prefer an approach where I don’t have to let Gradle generate an IntelliJ project but instead to let IntelliJ work with Gradle. However, that’ll require extracting the JAR file. A good Gradle solution for this would be the following:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

def unzipAlice = tasks.register('unzipAlice', Sync) {
    from(zipTree("${projectDir}/sources.jar"))
    into(temporaryDir)
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDir(unzipAlice)
```

This solution at least solves the “synchronization” problem mentioned in your question: the [`Sync` task](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Sync.html) makes sure that no updates to `sources.jar` are ignored (including deletions).

About the “editable” problem, I wonder why you don’t trust your developers here? They could produce all kind of nonsense in the rest of the code anyway. Or even if the JAR isn’t extracted, they could still replace the files in the JAR. With this extraction solution, IntelliJ at least warns if the sources are edited:

> Generated source files should not be edited. The changes will be lost when sources are regenerated.

Ok, if you run `./gradlew clean` then IntelliJ will indeed not find the sources anymore.  But this can easily be fixed by either calling “Build” → “Build Project” in the UI or by running “./gradlew unzipAlice”. If the “./gradlew clean” issue should really be a dealbreaker for the extracting approach, then you could still consider extracting the sources outside of the `build` directory …

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work in my environment, but I'm going to award the points for your effort. We took a hybrid approach that effectively has the same result as keeping the `.java` files within the `.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

We decided that extracting the `jar` file would be the best approach after all:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

final GENERATED_JAR = "${projectDir}/sources.jar"
final GENERATED_DIR = "${buildDir}/generated/sources"

task extractSources(type: Sync) {
  from zipTree(GENERATED_JAR)
  into GENERATED_DIR
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDir extractSources
clean.finalizedBy extractSources

idea.module.generatedSourceDirs += file(GENERATED_DIR)
```

This:

- Retains the generated sources after `clean`
- Issues a warning in the IDE when modifying generated sources
- Couples the build process to extracting source files
- Reuses the `build/generated/sources` path
- Keeps `.jar` file and `.java` files in synchronization

In effect, the following behaviours work as expected:

- `./gradlew clean` -- leaves the extracted `.java` files intact, effectively
- `./gradlew build` -- re-synchronizes `.java` files with `.jar` contents